# Room Database error with Kotlin Data Class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I've been moving into using Room, and I've run into a blocking issue. I've gone through and fixed all of the compile-time checks from the Room library, but am now encountering the following error:

```
Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
```

This appears twice at compile time with no evidence of which class this comes from, but I was able to figure out (by removing classes from the Database) that this was one of the files. I'm assuming it has something to do with the Primary Key being a string instead of an Int (this is one of two classes that uses this), but nothing in the documentation indicates what the issue would be, and in fact the documentation shows that strings are valid Primary Keys.

```
@Entity(tableName = "inspections")
data class Inspection(
@SerializedName("id")
var id: Int = 0,

...
// Rest of code left off for brevity, found to not be related to the issue.
```

I've tried a few things to try and get around this.

- Remove the data attribute of this class to make it a normal POKO
- Remove the variables from the default constructor, and place them into the class
- Remove the Ignore from the empty constructor (note, this causes a different issue, `Room cannot pick a constructor since multiple constructors are suitable` - the Ignore annotation on a default constructor gets around this.) This is the part which perplexes me the most - removing this says "multiple constructors are valid", keeping it says "no constructors are valid".

Updated: Adding a few more relevant code snippets from my project.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
.....
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha9-1'
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0-alpha9-1'
kapt 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9-1'
```

Database class

```
@Database(entities =
    arrayOf(Account::class, Category::class,
            Inspection::class, InspectionForm::class,
            InspectionFormItem::class, InspectionFormsStructure::class,
            InspectionItemPhoto::class,
            InspectionItem::class, LineItem::class,
            LocalPhoto::class, Rating::class,
            Structure::class, SupervisoryZone::class,
            Upload::class, User::class),
    version = 16)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class OrangeDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun inspectionDao(): InspectionDao

    abstract fun localDao(): LocalDao

    abstract fun ratingsDao(): RatingsDao

    abstract fun structureZoneDao(): StructureZoneDao

    abstract fun userAccountDao(): UserAccountDao
}
```

Converters

```
class Converters {
@TypeConverter
fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? {
    return if (value == null) Date() else Date(value)
}

@TypeConverter
fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?): Long? {
    return date?.time ?: 0
}

@TypeConverter
fun fromStringToArray(value: String?): Array<String>? {
    return value?.split(",")?.toTypedArray() ?: arrayOf()
}

@TypeConverter
fun stringToStringArray(strings: Array<String>?): String? {
    return strings?.joinToString(",") ?: ""
}
}
```

Another data class

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
data class User(
@PrimaryKey
@SerializedName("id")
var id: Int = 0,

...
// Rest of code left off for brevity, found to not be related to the issue.
```

UserPermissions class:

```
data class UserPermissions(
@SerializedName("id")
var pid: Int = 0,

...
// Rest of code left off for brevity, found to not be related to the issue.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was extremely difficult to debug and harder to reproduce, but I found the issue. I was using an `@Embedded` object, but the result that was going in was actually a `List` of that object. This was giving trouble to the automatic Embed task, and there wasn't a perfect Converter that could be written for it.

```
@SerializedName("range_choices")
@Embedded
var rangeChoices: List<RangeChoice>? = null,
```

I had to annotate that with `@Ignore` and instead, I'll be saving the results of this list to its own table, now the new table `range_choices`.

Comment: This works.. +1. Infact for those who do not want to use ignore, you can simply specify your typeconverter, but do not include @Embedded for a list of objects

Answer (score 20):

The problem in your case is, that if you have nullable values Kotlin will generate several constructors for each possible constructor.

That means that you have to define a default constructor and fill it with default values.

If you want to have another one which should be ignored you should make sure to use the parent constructor with all those parameters.

Example:

```
@Entity(tableName = "inspections")
data class Inspection(
@SerializedName("id")
var id: Int = 0,

@PrimaryKey
@SerializedName("guid")
var guid: String = "",

@SerializedName("score")
var score: Double = 0.0,

@SerializedName("notification_sent_at")
var notificationSentAt: Date = Date(),

var wasUploaded: Boolean = false)  {

@Ignore
constructor() : this(0, "", 0.0, Date(), false)
}
```

In this case only two constructors will be generated "under the hood". If you have nullable values you will have all possible constructors available.

Example:

```
data class Test(var id: Int = 0, var testString: String? = null, var testBool : Boolean? = null) {
   constructor(0)
}
```

generates

```
constructor(var id:Int)
constructor() : this(0)
constructor(var id:Int, var testString: String)
constructor(var id:Int, var testBool: Boolean) 
constructor(var id:Int, var testString: String, var testBool : Boolean)
// .. and so on
```

Since you'r looking for an official documentation, you may want to look at [Overloads Generation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html).

After testing your class which works flawlessly i found in another post that you have to check if you used `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in your Gradle.

Double check that you've valid type converters for your Date class. I wrote [that issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/43) longer time ago.

After recoding your stuff above it worked just fine by adding a UserPermissions class like that:

```
data class UserPermissions(var permissionid: String)
```

Edit: After using your UserPermission class everything worked just fine. Please take care if you use the proper import (util.Date instead of sql.Date for example).

Another problem is that your using an old very buggy library of room.

The current version (while writing this) is

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-beta2"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-beta2"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0-beta2"
```

I wrote [an issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/172) long time ago

Comment: The error message I'm encountering from the Room library reads `Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).` What you are suggesting, and what I found, is that these constructors all exist, including one that has all parameters that match the fields.

Comment: Ive added your class to my project and it works flawlessly. Even after cleaning the project, invalidating cache, and so on. Could you please post your Gradle files

Comment: I've posted the relevant Gradle snippet, as well as a few other files in the implementation.

Comment: Please post the class UserPermissions. I have completly recoded your stuff above and it compiles just fine by adding a UserPermissions class which contains only a "permissionID" as param.

Comment: Added the full UserPermissions class to the post. Very odd that you're able to use everything without issues.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I've updated to the newest version (as of now rc1 is the newest), and the same issue appears. The update did point out a few issues with two of my classes having a PrimaryKey var that was nullable, but after fixing that, the same error message is popping up two times without any context.

Comment: After changing to rc1 you need to clean your project and invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Have done so multiple times. Still getting that same dumb error.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, I was finally able to narrow it down. Left an answer for the response, but awarded the bounty to you for the awesome troubleshooting help. Thank you again!

Comment: Still not sure why these errors started going away when I was removing the OTHER classes that weren't actually the cause. That's what originally led me to believe the issue was in the class pasted in the original question.

Comment: Thank you, and thank you for posting the answer. Regarding the "hard to debug" i left an issue a few month ago (straight after release) in the aac github ;-) ive spent two days finding that issue a long time ago

Comment: Are you sure about "if you have nullable values Kotlin will generate several constructors for each possible constructor"? [The docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#overloads-generation) say they are generated for parameters with default values, regardless of their nullability, and at most one (empty) constructor is generated without `@JvmOverloads`.

Answer (score 1):

Your Primary keys should be like given below using [Annotation Use-site Targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets)

```
@field:PrimaryKey @field:SerializedName("guid") var guid: String = ""
```

and

```
@field:PrimaryKey @field:SerializedName("id") var id: Int = 0
```

Comment: Are you sure that you understand the use of kotlin based annotations? ;-)

Comment: @EmanuelS It will be nice of you if you point out the exact problem in the use of kotlin based annotations. I have attached the official document as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using nullable values and make everything have some kind of default value. That's the simpliest way to solve this issue.

If you really want to use them, then you may create a constructor, containing all of them.